# Select all columns with Shiny datatables

Tags: r, shiny, dt

With Shiny datatables, one can select table columns by clicking the corresponding table cells, and then the selected columns are highlighted. But in case there are too many columns, is there any way that one can just click a button to select all columns and highlight them? In this way, one can deselect some columns by clicking corresponding cells.

---

P.S. my current solution: I made a checkbox indicating that the user can invert select the columns. When the check box is checked, the highlighted columns will be excluded from the selected set instead of being included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this could be a way to do it.

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)


    shinyUI(fluidPage(


      titlePanel("Column Selection"),
      fluidRow(
              actionButton("selectCols", "Select all columns"), 
              DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'),
              verbatimTextOutput("selectedColums")
        )

    ))
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {


            irisTable <- reactive({
                    if (input$selectCols > 0) {
                            datatable(iris, selection = list(target = 'column', selected = c(0,1,2,3,4,5)))   
                    } else {
                            datatable(iris, selection = list(target = 'column'))  
                    }
            })

            output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
                    irisTable())
            output$selectedColums <- renderPrint({
                    input$tbl_columns_selected
            })

    })
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this will work. But I'd like also highlight the selected columns. This may need some extra work with Javascript though. In that way, I can also click the selected column to deselect it.

Comment: When you click the button all columns are selected and greyed. Once all the columns are selected clicking on any one column deselects it and makes it white. You wanted a different behavior?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Yes, this is what I want. Thanks again.